# Windows 8 64bit desktop, action center and windows solutions

Tags: windows-8, action-center

So I run my windows 8 with two user accounts. Admin for anything relating to changes to services and similar. And a normal user account for installing programs, games and so on.
Now here is the issue I find odd, and have no solution on.

After some trial and error I found where I edit windows error reporting so I actually see the crash report when a program crash. And I have received a solution to review, but anytime I try to access it, I get the message "Your not connected to internet, please try again or check your connection". If I on the other hand log on to my admin account I can access solutions there, but I can't find the solutions for my user account. Would someone know how to fix this so I can see what windows thinks I should do?